# Job result is the Post Script result

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building a pipeline and I have two post-build scripts in case of success and unsuccess.

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo 'Building...'

            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
post {
    unsuccessful {
        script {
                build job: '../declinePullRequests'
            }
        }
    }
    success {
        script {
               build job: '../createPR_mergePR'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, I want my job to return immediatly after it finishes, and not to get blocked by the post-build step. Basically, if the post-script fails, the main job console shows:

> Error when executing success post condition:
>   hudson.AbortException: createPR_mergePR #40 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerListener.onCompleted(BuildTriggerListener.java:52)
>       at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireCompleted(RunListener.java:211)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1861)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)

And the main job fails due to failure in post-script job, though it was successful before it. I've researched in the docs and cannot find a solution for it.

How can my main job *return immediately after being finished*, independently from the post-script job result?

I don't only want to keep the original job state but also *not to wait for the child job to get the main job finished*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the properties `propagate` and `wait` explicitly to `false`.

`build job: '../declinePullRequests', propagate: false, wait: false`

Comment: That's it man. So simple yet so hard to find (docs are not explicit in my opinion). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi looks like you what to spawn processes which run even when the original build is finished. If its possible to pack your scripts into shell/batch, take a look at this two sites:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218517228-How-to-Ignore-Failures-in-a-Shell-Step-